# Is the inverse limit an additive functor in the category of $R$-mod?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is the inverse limit an additive functor in the categories of $R$-mod?

Equivalently, if we have two inverse systems $\{A_i\}$ and $\{B_i\}$ of $R$-modules sharing the same index set, do we have
$$
\lim_{\leftarrow} A_i \oplus B_i = \lim_{\leftarrow} A_i \oplus  \lim_{\leftarrow}  B_i?
$$

Comment: You get this for free: The (finite direct sum) is a finite product, which is a limit. Since limits commute with each other, you win.

Comment: @Geoff Thank you